# coffeescript - run after page load

Tags: coffeescript

I'm very new to CoffeScript and want to edit some code that I found.  Right now, it runs this function right when the DOM is loaded:

```
jQuery ->   
 $('#s3-uploader').S3Uploader
```

How can I rewrite it such that it only runs after the page is loaded?  I need to wait so I can get the correct instance variables:

```
(on page load) ->   
 $('#s3-uploader').S3Uploader
    additional_data: {project_id: @project.id, step_id: @step.id, user_id: current_user.id}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is quite an old question, and no doubt you have found a solution already. But for the benefit of anyone coming here from Google....

It is also not 100% clear from your question, but you appear to be using a framework such as Ruby on Rails.

If so, then the correct answer of course is that you should not be accessing instance variables from Coffeescript. Coffeescript files in the asset pipeline are compiled during deployment, and have no knowledge of the controller or instance variables.

The correct way is to assign these variables to data attributes in the DOM, and then reference the data attributes.

```
#view.html.erb
<div id="uploader" data-project_id="<%= @project.id %>" ></div>

#script.coffee.js
(on page load) ->   
 $('#s3-uploader').S3Uploader
    additional_data: {project_id: $('#uploader').data('project_id') .... }
```

Comment: Ding ding ding, I think we have a winner

Answer (score 2):

For rails, this worked for me when all the other answers here did not:

```
$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `$(document).ready` event handler.

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('#s3-uploader').S3Uploader
```

Comment: I don't think this is right...I need to run after the instance variables are loaded, so it can't be when the DOM is loaded.  I tried $(window).load () -> but this doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

```
checkVariable = ->
  if variableLoaded == true
    # here is your next action 
  else
  return

setTimeout 'checkVariable()', 1000
```